# How to access variable inside mongodb to compare in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to compare email in db with the email entered by the user. I have set up my db schema like this.

[Database UserSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIHKV.png)

but when i try to access the email to compare with the email entered by the user using this :
 User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }) .

it shows an error.

Please tell me how can I access the email in local.

Comment: Post the code what you have tried??

Comment: Hi Uday Saini, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I make a suggestion about your question? You could improve it if you copy your database schema into the question (instead of linking to a screenshot); and also use [appropriate formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), for example on your query. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] your questions to improve them as much as possible.

Comment: @VinceBowdren sorry man new to StackOverflow. its a bit complicated. and Ive completed my project and everything works fine. It was a UserManagement system with Login, SignUp and reset password.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.findOne({ 'local.email': req.body.email }) .
```

Comment: @Subburaj No, I think it's a valid answer. Certainly it looks like the right kind of query.

Comment: Hi wostex; your query might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: @Vince Bowdren I didn't say its invalid answer,, But this could be conveyed in a comment...

Comment: Sorry if my answer is unclear in some way, but it's self-explanatory if you look at UserSchema image linked in the question. The guy has a nested object, and he should access a nested property as shown in my answer.

Comment: @wostex it did help thanks. by the way how to use a url component into a ejs file ?!